# html css table td control adjust width based on screen resolution and content

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have a react js app where 1 page has a table with tbody, tr, and td. The table has only two  columns aka td tags. I would like the first column to automatically adjust the screen resolution  and content. I tried width:"fit-content", width:"auto", but  the width is about 50% of the table width. It only works when I change it to width:"20%" but the width is not correct for different resolution. I read other posts here but have not found anything that works so far. Here is my code so far

```
<table className="myTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td width="fit-content">
       <control1/>
     <td width="auto" > 
  <control2/>
     </td>
    </td>
  </tbody>
</table>

//css
.myTable
  table-layout: fixed
   width: 100%
```

I tried table-layout: auto but my table runs off the page so I think I need to keep it fixed. but the width on the first td is does not correctly to its content.

Answer (score 1):

You may try `<td style="width:20vw">`, to fix the colum width to 20% of the viewport's resolution.